# Можно ли управлять телефоном когда он выключен?

Tags: java, android

Интересует информация можно ли управлять телефоном из приложения когда он выключен? Интересует любая информация для изучения по этому поводу. Суть состоит в том что бы создать что то вроде будильника по которому телефон бы включался!

Comment: Скорее всего можно в следующей схеме: запланировать будильник на определенное время и к этому же времени задать [запланированное оповещение](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms), которое вызовет приложение

Comment: Могу вас разочаровать, но на всех моих устройствах телефон включается по будильнику.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно интернету, множество производителей устройств планируют включение устройства за несколько минут до будильника, чтобы последний мог прозвенеть. Но, стоит отметить, что подход у разных производителей тоже отличается: некоторые телефоны Xiaomi например, запускают будильник без запуска самой операционной системы.

Исходя из вышесказанного, могу сделать вывод, что хоть и такое теоретически можно сделать, но в реальности оперирование с глубинными инструкциями системы, уникальными для каждого производителя, а также вполне возможно, изолированными от внешнего воздействия, близится к невозможному.